# SSIS take -1 hour from current date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, ssis, getdate

I am new at SSIS currently trying to do is to get 1 hr less from current time

I am using

```
(DT_DATE) GETDATE()
```

My Output is:

```
27/02/2017 4:24:09 PM
```

My Expected output is:

```
27/02/2017 3:24:09 PM
```

Can please someone help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following expression

```
DATEADD("Hh",-1, GETDATE())
```

Read more about `DATEADD` In this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx)

*Side Note: `GETDATE()` is a function that returns the current date and doesn't need to be parsed using `(DT_DATE) GETDATE()`*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DATEADD(HOUR,-1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: That expression cant be evaluated.. I use DataType as DateTime and still the error says " The expression contains unrecognized token " HOUR"

Answer (score 0):

Could you try  `DATEADD("Hour",-1, GETDATE())` ? Without the `DT_DATE`..